# UICollectionViewCell is populating on 0th section only

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have created a `UICollectionView` on `storyboard` a created a custom cell, number of sections are 5 but cell is appearing for top most section only.

My Code is -

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionReusableView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "MyHeaderView");
}


func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 5
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("PSCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PSCollectionViewCell
    cell.frame = cell.bounds
    return cell
}
```

Comment: put some data then check it.

Comment: Have you set your data source and delegate correctly in interface builder? e.g. does your `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` even get called?

Comment: Yes, i have a UIImageView in my  PSCollectionViewCell.

Comment: @prem why you have taken 1 row only ?

Comment: @MayankPatel , i need horizontal collection view in row and i need a header too so i have decided to create multiple sections instead of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the code -

```
cell.frame = cell.bounds
```